# How to check whether a music is playing or paused in AudioQueue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio, audioqueueservices

I am using **AudioQueueStart** for playing music and **AudioQueuePause** for pausing. Is there any way in AudioQueues to check whether the music is playing or not, I want to Pause music only if it is playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning` property with `AudioQueueGetProperty`.

Or seeing as you're the one stopping and starting the queue, just remember the state you set and act accordingly.